# Find a regular expression for following string

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-4

I have string and that string has four formats:

```
str = "A. B.C. D, WOW, 'H' BENCH"

str1 = "ABCD WOW BENCH \"k\""

str2 = "A.B.C.D,. WOW 'K' BENCH"

str3 = "ABCD, WOW 'K' BENCH"
```

The string will come in any one of the formats, so I want the regular expression which will give me the following results respectively:

```
str = "ABCD WOW H BENCH"

str1 = "ABCD WOW BENCH K"

str2 = "ABCD WOW K BENCH"

str3 = "ABCD WOW K BENCH"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex and then replace the match with an empty string:

```
(?<=\.) (?=[A-Z]\b)|[.,'"]
```

Here is a [demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/qB0jV1/12).

Comment: The above expression is not working if the string is like `"A. B.C D., WOW K Bench"` it is giving the `ABC D WOW K Bench`output. I want the output `ABCD WOW K Bench`

Comment: @DeeptiKakade please add some explanation to your question. What would be the expected output for the above input and why? And it's better to ask it as a new question.